# How to extract every blog, its category and its subcategory?

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

This is my scheme.

- blog (idblog, title, description, date, foundername)
- category (idcategory, categoryname, idsub)
- assigned (idblog, idcategory)

I perfectly understand how to extract every blog based on its category or on its subcategory. For example to extract all the information about all the blogs which are in a category of Front End Development, I use this query:

```
SELECT blog.idblog, blog.title, blog.description, blog.date, category.categoryname
FROM blog, assigned, category
WHERE blog.idblog = assigned.idblog AND assigned.idcategory = category.idcategory
AND category.categoryname LIKE 'Front End Development'
```

In this case, what I'm trying to achieve is to extract the same info but with the addition of the subcategory name, which can be null as well.

Thank you.

Comment: Start by goofling up "JOIN" in Sql/Mysql. This will set you on the right way, and are spo fundamental that you cannot do without. You will have to know about them.

Comment: @Roemer I perfectly understand this as well. Sadly, this is a college project and I'm forced to follow my professor's method.

Comment: Your schema doesn't seem to have a subcategory. It is not clear, what you tried and where you did fail. Do you need help with a query?

Comment: Is the `idsub` in your `category` table supposed to determine what is a parent and what is a sub category? (Then each category could only have a maximum of one sub category? The usual approach is the other way around - the ID of the _parent_ gets recorded, and set to 0/NULL, if it is a top level category.)

Comment: also, why do you use like operator for an exact comparison?

Comment: @Uwe Let's say that we have the category 'Web Design and Development' with idcategory of 1. Then all the subcategories like Front End Dev. will have idcategory = 2, categoryname ='Front End Dev' and idsub = '1', meaning it is a subcategory of the category with idcategory 1.

Comment: @LelioFaieta I was in a rush while rewriting my query. My bad.

Comment: @CBroe, idsub determines the parent category of a specific subcategory as I explained in the previous example. The main categories have the idsub set to NULL, as you said.

Comment: Ah, just a case of really terrible and absolutely counter-intuitive naming then :-)

Comment: @CBroe, yeah, parentid would have been a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your professor makes no sense, JOIN is vital here. Can't do it any other way I can thing of. Try

```
SELECT blog.idblog, blog.title, blog.description, blog.date, category.categoryname, subcategory.categoryname as subcategoryname
FROM blog 
     LEFT JOIN assigned ON blog.idblog = assigned.idblog
     LEFT JOIN category ON assigned.idcategory = category.idcategory
     LEFT JOIN category AS subcategory ON category.idsub = subcategory.idcategory 
WHERE  category.categoryname LIKE 'Front End Development'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this solution but it appears that I just get the category but not my subcategory. This is an example of what I got:
25, Lorem, 2022-08-22 11:16:52, Front End Development, NULL
26, Front End Dealers, 2022-08-22 11:17:01, Front End Development, NULL.

In this case NULL is basically the subcategoryname, which should be, for example, "REACT", "ANGULAR", etc.

Comment: You must show your data then. You give us too little information, I was guessing how you implemted the subcategory (apparently not the standard way).